# Заполнить матрицу по спирали

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Не смог найти библиотеку, которая позволяет заполнить матрицу по спирали, например так:

```
1 2 3    
8 9 4    
7 6 5
```

или наоборот - из центра наружу.

Кто знает, как это сделать самому?

Comment: Ваша задача относится к "нетривиальным". Возможно какие-то особые либы это умеют... Думаю что такой библиотеки нету.

Comment: А это может где-то понадобиться кроме учебного задания? Если может, то есть смысл поискать по интернету, в противном же случае стоит искать решение учебного задания. Либо реализовать это самостоятельно

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск библиотек, плагинов - оффтопик для so. Спрашивайте про алгоритм такого заполнения, код, пробуйте сами написать.

Comment: @AK, можно пруф с цитатой что это оффтопик?

Comment: для этого надо писать свой алгоритм, для этого и есть задача

Comment: @4per [Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) + [толкования на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Comment: @Regent Знаю одно практическое применение - http://hijos.ru/2013/02/08/najdeno-novoe-prostoe-chislo-sostoyashhee-iz-17-millionov-cifr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод `getSpiralMatrix()` реализованный ниже:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SpiralMatrix {

    public int[][] getSpiralMatrix(int n, boolean reverse) {
        int [][] matrix = new int[n][];
        IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i -> matrix[i] = new int[n]);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = n;
        for (int i = 0, j = n * n; i < j;) {
            matrix[x][y] = reverse ? j - i++ : ++i;

            if (x < z + (n - z) / 2 - 1 && y == (n - z) / 2) {
                x++;
            } else if (x == z + (n - z) / 2 - 1 && y < z + (n - z) / 2 - 1) {
                y++;
            } else if (x > (n - z) / 2 && y == z + (n - z) / 2 - 1) {
                x--;
            } else if (x == (n - z) / 2 && y > (n - z) / 2 + 1) {
                y--;
            } else {
                x++;
                z -= 2;
            }
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpiralMatrix sp = new SpiralMatrix();
        int n = 9;

        int[][] matrix = sp.getSpiralMatrix(n, true);
        printMatrix(matrix);

        System.out.println("===========================");

        matrix = sp.getSpiralMatrix(n, false);
        printMatrix(matrix);
    }

    private static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        IntStream.range(0, matrix.length).forEach(i -> {
            IntStream.range(0, matrix.length).forEach(j -> System.out.printf("%02d ", matrix[j][i]));
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
}
```

Этот демонстрационный код напечатает:

```
81 80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 
50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 72 
51 26 25 24 23 22 21 42 71 
52 27 10 09 08 07 20 41 70 
53 28 11 02 01 06 19 40 69 
54 29 12 03 04 05 18 39 68 
55 30 13 14 15 16 17 38 67 
56 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 66 
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 
===========================
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 10 
31 56 57 58 59 60 61 40 11 
30 55 72 73 74 75 62 41 12 
29 54 71 80 81 76 63 42 13 
28 53 70 79 78 77 64 43 14 
27 52 69 68 67 66 65 44 15 
26 51 50 49 48 47 46 45 16 
25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17
```

Comment: Похоже на перемотку магнитной ленты на другую катушку ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// на PascalABC.net 
//Матрица по спирали из любого угла или из центра, по часовой или против часовой

begin
  var n:= 3;
  var ИзЦентра := 0; // 0 - из угла  1 - из Центра

  Var Центр := Ceil(n / 2) - 1; //Координата центра матрицы  
  var (i, j, Направление, nEven) := (0, 0, 1, n.IsEven ? 1 : 0); // с левого верхнего 
  if ИзЦентра = 1 then (i, j, Направление, nEven) := (Центр, Центр, 1, 0); // из центра
  var Матрица := new integer[n,n];
  for var Элемент := 1 to n*n do
   begin
      Матрица[i,j]:= Элемент; {
[i,j] - с левого верхнего по часовой;  из Центра вправо по часовой
[j,i] - с левого верхнего против часовой;  из Центра вниз против часовой
[n-1-i,j] - с левого нижнего против часовой;  из Центра вправо против часовой
[n-1-j,i] - с левого нижнего по часовой;  из центра вверх по часовой
[j,n-1-i] - с правго верхнего по часовой;  из Центра вниз по часовой 
[i,n-1-j] - c правго верхнего против часовой;  из Центра влево против часовой
[n-1-i,n-1-j] - c правого нижнего по часовой;  из Центра влево по часовой
[n-1-j,n-1-i] - c правого нижнего против часовой;  из центра вверх по часовой
}
       case Направление of 
         1:begin {вправо}              
           inc(j);           
           if (Центр - i + ИзЦентра ) = (j - Центр - nEven)  then Направление := 2;           
           end;
         2:begin {вниз}               
           inc(i);           
           if i = j  then Направление := 3;
           end;
         3:begin {влево}
           dec(j);
           if (i - Центр) = (Центр - j  + nEven) then Направление := 4;
           end;
         4:begin {вверх}
           dec(i);
           if (i - 1) = (j - ИзЦентра)   then Направление := 1;
           end
       end;
    end;
  Матрица.Println;
end.
```